# List Comprehensions: How do I crank out a new list for every loop iteration of x where an item in both "lists" match?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
allDasTickets = ["9255955", "9255958", "9255960", "9255977"]
[j for j in allDasTickets for x in allDasTickets if x != j]
```

So I get an list of the following lists:

```
['9255958', '9255960', '9255977']
['9255955', '9255958', '9255977']
['9255958', '9255960', '9255977']
['9255955', '9255958', '9255960']
```

i.e. a list with the matching one missing (I hope that's what I've put above)

Comment: P.S. I probably should have used a set

Comment: Is the third row meant to start with `'9255955'` it is currently just a dupe of the first row.

Comment: No.  They're supposed to all be unique

Comment: Since there are 4 items in the list, and the list is being compared to itself, the item that matches should crank out a list of everything but the item that matches.

Comment: I wrote this up pretty quick so I had a feeling I screwed something up in my example.

Comment: Like `itertools.combinations(a, len(a) - 1)`?

Comment: @DanD. I don't know

Comment: @DanD. the order would be wrong, but maybe reversed would work (and in py3 you would need to wrap it in `list(...)` as a list was asked for).

Comment: If this clears it up at all, basically what I'm doing is I get one phone call from one store and they have several issues, for which I have to open several tickets about and then I need to add references to the other tickets from each ticket, and so I want to have a list of all except the current one.  And also I'm trying to learn about list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the inner brackets. You need them because you're trying to generate a list of lists, instead of just a flat list.

```
allDasTickets = ["9255955", "9255958", "9255960", "9255977"]
[[j for j in allDasTickets if x != j] for x in allDasTickets]
```

yields

```
[['9255958', '9255960', '9255977'],
 ['9255955', '9255960', '9255977'],
 ['9255955', '9255958', '9255977'],
 ['9255955', '9255958', '9255960']]
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939742/list-comprehensions-why-this-lc-work-this-way-but-not-in-reverse?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Reversing works. Your given output has `['9255958', '9255960', '9255977']` twice and leave out `['9255955', '9255960', '9255977']`.

```
import itertools
allDasTickets = ["9255955", "9255958", "9255960", "9255977"]
for t in itertools.combinations(reversed(allDasTickets), len(allDasTickets) - 1):
    print(list(reversed(t)))
```

Prints:

```
['9255958', '9255960', '9255977']
['9255955', '9255960', '9255977']
['9255955', '9255958', '9255977']
['9255955', '9255958', '9255960']
```