# Understanding the syntax of list comprehensions (and nested LCs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, list-comprehension

This works:

```
allDasTickets = ["9255955", "9255958", "9255960", "9255977"]
[[j for j in allDasTickets if x != j] for x in allDasTickets]

['9255958', '9255960', '9255977']
['9255955', '9255958', '9255977']
['9255958', '9255960', '9255977']
['9255955', '9255958', '9255960']
```

But this does not:

```
allDasTickets = ["9255955", "9255958", "9255960", "9255977"]
[for x in allDasTickets [j for j in allDasTickets if x != j]]
File "<stdin>", line 1
[for x in allDasTickets [j for j in allDasTickets if x != j]]
   ^
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939433/list-comprehensions-how-do-i-crank-out-a-new-list-for-every-loop-iteration-of-x

Comment: I don't see why you would have expected that to work. The syntax just isn't defined that way. It's `[a for b in c]`, not `[for b in c a]`.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think it's that I expected it to work, it's just that I keep screwing it up and wondering why.  If I have a reason why it's screwed up, I'll remember it better.

Comment: @coldspeed Wow I'm honored to get an upvote from you (if that's you)

Comment: I always upvote questions that I answer (because that means it is a question worth answering, at least in my eyes) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For list comprehensions, the syntax is

```
[ <something> for elem in sequence]
```

Where `<something>` can itself be a list comprehension. Meanwhile, for nested loop (but not nested lists) comprehensions, the syntax is

```
[<something> for elem in outerseq for elem2 in innerseq]
```

In the same way, and so on.